# Problemas con arrays

Tags: php

El objetivo es copiar una línea
Mediante el siguiente código , obtengo la línea origen  de la tabla facturagastolineas

```
$linea = $this->repoFacturaGastoLinea->getModel()->where('id','=',$id)->get();
```

La línea obtenida es la siguiente:
[{"id":785,"suscriptor_id":7,"factura_id":479,"subcuenta_id":1010,"concepto_id":24,"extensionconcepto":"123456 rui sl.","baseimponible":"200.00","tipoiva":"21.00","cuotadeiva":"0.00","created_at":"2020-10-04 13:44:28","updated_at":"2020-10-04 13:44:28"}]

` Dicha línea he de enviarla a repoFacturaGastoLinea mediante el siguiente código:

```
$nuevalinea = $this->repoFacturaGastoLinea->create($linea );
```

La function que recibe la información  espera un array($datos)

```
public function create( array $datos ) {
    //-- Creamos una Línea de factura.
    $linea = $this->getModel()->create( [
                    "suscriptor_id"=>$datos['suscriptor_id'],
                        'factura_id' => $datos['factura_id'] ,
                    'subcuenta_id'=>$datos['id_subcuenta'],
                              'tipoiva'=>DataConverter::convertNumberSpanishToEnglish($datos['tipodeiva']),
                  'baseimponible'=>DataConverter::convertNumberSpanishToEnglish($datos['baseimponible'] ),
                      'concepto_id'=>$datos['concepto_id'],
            'extensionconcepto'=>$datos['extensionconcepto'],
                      'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
                      'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ] );
    $this->repoActividad->create( "facturagastolineas" , "añadir" , $linea );
    $this->repoRepositorio->create( "facturagastolineas" , $linea );
    return $linea;
}
```

El formato de $linea no se corresponde con el esperado por create , ya que lanza un mensaje de error.

Local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\FacturaGastoLineaRepository::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\orzo\proyectos\comgest\app\Http\Controllers\FacturaGastoLineaController.php on line 222 in C:\orzo\proyectos\comgest\app\Repositories\FacturaGastoLineaRepository.php:54.

¿Qué tipo de objeto es $linea?.

¿Cómo puedo convertirlo en un array que pueda ser aceptado por create?.

Espero haberme explicado .

Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: ¿Existe el método `->toArray();` en el ORM que usas? ¿funciona si lo encadenas después de `get()`?
Has probado una conversión explicita: `(array) $objeto`.

Comment: @orici: Acepta ->toArray() y el resultado es el siguiente. array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 785,
    'suscriptor_id' => 7,
    'factura_id' => 479,
    'subcuenta_id' => 1010,
    'concepto_id' => 24,
    'extensionconcepto' => '123456 rui sl.',
    'baseimponible' => '200.00',
    'tipoiva' => '21.00',
    'cuotadeiva' => '0.00',
    'created_at' => '2020-10-04 13:44:28',
    'updated_at' => '2020-10-04 13:44:28',
  ),
)  
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined index: suscriptor_id in app\Repositories\FacturaGastoLineaRepository.php:57,function create de la pregunta

Comment: Con ese resultado, tienes que hacer el acceso a datos de este modo: `$linea[0]['suscriptor_id]` y no `$linea['suscriptor_id]`. O bien cambiar como obtienes los datos: con la *sintaxis que uso en Laravel* sería: `$linea = $this->repoFacturaGastoLinea->getModel()->where('id','=',$id)->first()->toArray();`